# Videos in SharePoint with simultaneous access

Tags: 2013, video

Has anybody experienced problems with playing videos from SharePoint simultaneously?

As an example, if users uploaded lots of videos of several sizes, even high quality which can be very big (I have examples of videos of 0,5 and 1gb) in something like a video repository, we would easily reach the limit of 200gb of database first of all. But I am more concerned about a situation where several people would access several videos or the same video at the same time, which can be very big.

How would SharePoint perform in a situation like this? Would the database server be blocked, or can it handle it easily? Has anybody had issues like this before that can be shared?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200GB isn't a 'limit'. You can go above and beyond 200GB.

You should put videos on a Publishing site and enable BLOBCache. By doing so, users can pick up the video from the SharePoint server file system rather than having to go back to the Content Database.

There are better solutions for videos, such as IIS Streaming Media Server or Azure services. Something to consider.

Comment: You are right :) "Recommended capacity". I quickly read this post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2013/03/29/corporate-youtube-and-video-delivery-via-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I have Blobcache activated in the web application. Unfortunately, we have 2 ISS sites (HTTP and HTTPS) for it, so the cache is actually duplicated. Do we just need to make the cache drive big enough to hold this amount of information? 
Does the publishing site make a difference between normal sites, or publishing sites for video management?

Comment: Publishing sites are the only ones that create/use BLOBCache (or sites with Publishing features enabled). You should make sure that volume does have enough space available, and yes it will be duplicated.